# Suitable http status code to state the browser is not supported?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, rest, cross-browser, http-headers

I'm not supporting IE8 and below, and based on a useragent checked all requests made from one of these browsers are referred to a page where I explain the reason and display links to supported browsers.

Is there an HTTP status code to go along with this? 200 Wouldn't be right because the user is not getting the page he requested and 505 (Version not supported) refers to an outdated HTTP version, which is also not the case.

Comment: instead of trying that , detect the browser client side or better , display a alert message or whatever with css only if it is IE8 or lower , you dont need no scripting for that.

Comment: I think, there is no special HTTP response status for your case. 505 - it's HTTP version not supported, like web agent use HTTP/1.1 but HTTP server supports only HTTP/1.0

Comment: You could use a 402 "payment required" and put a donation page to collect funds to hire a developer to build IE8 support :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I vote for

403 Forbidden "The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it"

but there's no definitive answer to this.

Comment: me to, i'm inclined towards not using anything. you are after all returning a valid page

Comment: I think some code would be good to use, just like when you do a custom 404 page.  You still flag status as a 404 even if you put content in the body returned to the client.

Comment: good point, but this is an internal management decision, rather than an 'error'. "*600 - We don't serve your kind in here*"

Comment: I guess this is technically the best option available. It is indeed a management decision, but just as much as a 401 or 402 would be. I'll use free code 419 internally for statistics and routing, and output 403 headers & code to the client.

Comment: 403 is not appropriate. Read http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#section-7.5.3 which clearly shows 403 is intended for authorization problems, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

400 Bad Request

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx):

> BadRequest Equivalent to HTTP status 400. BadRequest indicates that
>   the request could not be understood by the server. **BadRequest is
>   sent when no other error is applicable**, or if the exact error is
>   unknown **or does not have its own error code**.

Answer (score 1):

I would use: 406 Not Acceptable

Note: This is technically misleading, because it not officially an issue with the client's Accept header, you're just trying to block a specific browser.

Whatever you do, go with a 4xx code.  The 5xx's are for server issues, while the 4xx's are for client issues--in this case not using a supported browsers.